# Redirecting the previous page after deleting a record

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm a newbee in CI. I'm hoping that you can help me with my problem. :)
I am trying to redirect the previous page in my site which has the table containing the data from the database. I keep on getting the message

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\..... 
Call to a member function result() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\findiningcebu.com\application\views\admin\SearchRestoDisplay.php on line 122
```

and the notice that says

```
Undefined variable: restaurantinfo....Backtrace:    
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\findiningcebu.com\application\views\admin\SearchRestoDisplay.php
Line: 122
```

Here are my codes:

View:

```
<div class = "list">
<table border=2>
<tr style="font-size: 16px; background-color: rgba(26, 26, 38, 0.5);">
<th>Name</th>
<th>Logo</th>
<th>Cuisine</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>

    <?php
      $restoname= ''; 
      $restologo= '';
      $cuisine= '';

      foreach($restaurantinfo->result() as $row) 
      { 
        $restoname= $row->restoname; 
        $restologo= $row->restologo;
        $cuisine= $row->cuisine;
       ?>
```

Controller:

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $this->load->model('AdminModel');
    $delete = $this->AdminModel->delete($id);
    $this->load->view('admin/SearchRestoDisplay');
}

 public function searchresto()
{
    $restoinfo = $_POST['restoinfo'];
    $searchinfo = $_POST['searchinfo'];

    $this->load->model('AdminModel');
    $restaurantinfo['restoinfo'] = $restoinfo;
    $restaurantinfo['searchinfo'] = $searchinfo;
    $restaurantinfo['restaurantinfo']=$this->AdminModel->searchrestaurant($restoinfo,$searchinfo);
    $this->load->view('admin/SearchRestoDisplay',$restaurantinfo);
}
```

Model:

```
public function delete($id){
$this->db->delete('restaurants',array('id'=>$id));
}
```

Comment: can you paste your `$this->AdminModel->searchrestaurant`, so we can se your `return`

Comment: public function searchrestaurant($restoinfo, $searchinfo)
 {
  $restaurantinfo = $this->db->get_where('restaurants',array($restoinfo=>$searchinfo));
        return $restaurantinfo;
 }

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `result()` is a method of the database class and you are trying to use this method on your `$restaurantinfo` and this looks like a simple array.

I recommend you that your `$this->AdminModel->searchrestaurant` returns something like this

```
 function searchrestaurant(){
   /*stuff*/
   return $query->result_array(); 
}
```

this way you can simply foreach this on your view

```
foreach($restaurantinfo as $row) 
      { 
        $restoname= $row['restoname']; 
        $restologo= $row['restologo'];
        $cuisine= $row['cuisine'];
      }
```

The problem looks like you are trying to use a method of the database class on your view, where your query does not exists.

So, change the `searchrestaurant` function, or do the query on the view.. thing that I don't really recommend...

Hope that helps

Comment: i tried this but it did not work for me. But, thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your delete function when you load the view, you don't pass the value '$restauranrinfo' that's why the restaurant details is missing in view. Fetch the restaurant details from database before load the view and pass the value in view.

Comment: i did something like this: $this->load->view('admin/SearchRestoDisplay', $restuarantinfo);.... it didn't work

Comment: When you pass $restaurantinfo,check the array value by print_r(array name)

Comment: You have to pass $restoinfo and $searchinfo value in delete function like the way you pass $id

Comment: i tried doing it like this: public function delete($id, $restoinfo, $searchinfo)
 {
        $this->load->model('AdminModel');
        $delete = $this->AdminModel->delete($id);
  $this->load->view('admin/SearchRestoDisplay', $restaurantinfo);....

Comment: and then i tried: public function delete($id, $restaurantinfo)
 {
        $this->load->model('AdminModel');
        $delete = $this->AdminModel->delete($id);
  $this->load->view('admin/SearchRestoDisplay', $restaurantinfo);...

Comment: i also tried: public function delete($id)
 {
        $this->load->model('AdminModel');
        $delete = $this->AdminModel->delete($id);
  $this->load->view('admin/SearchRestoDisplay', $restaurantinfo);.... none of it worked.. I just can't get it right

Comment: $this->load->model('AdminModel'); $restaurantinfo['restoinfo'] = $restoinfo; $restaurantinfo['searchinfo'] = $searchinfo; $restaurantinfo['restaurantinfo']=$this->AdminModel->searchrestaurant($restoinfo,$searchinfo); $this->load->view('admin/SearchRestoDisplay',$restaurantinfo); use this code after passing 3 arguments and check agreements are passing properly or not